# My script is not running successfully every time. After running sometimes it runs successfully for 1 time and next time when I run again it fails

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver

My script is not running successfully every time. After running sometimes it runs successfully for 1 time and next time when I run again it fails. 
package Example;

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import jxl.Sheet;
import jxl.Workbook;
import jxl.write.Label;
import jxl.write.WritableSheet;
import jxl.write.WritableWorkbook;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;

public class Script1 
{
public static void main(String args[])throws Exception
{
    //Take the data from input xls file
    FileInputStream fi =new FileInputStream("D:\\selenium_test\\Object 
       Repositoty\\Input\\Login1.xls");
    Workbook wb = Workbook.getWorkbook(fi);
    Sheet sh = wb.getSheet(0);

    //Create the Result xls file
    FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream("D:\\selenium_test\\Object   
  Repositoty\\Output\\Login_Results1.xls");
    WritableWorkbook wwb = Workbook.createWorkbook(fo);
    WritableSheet ws = wwb.createSheet("Results", 0);
    Thread.sleep(20000);

    String msg = "";

    WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.700creditsolution.com");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    Set<String> windowids = driver.getWindowHandles();
    Iterator<String> iter= windowids.iterator();
    for (int i = 1; i < sh.getRows(); i++)
    {   
    while(iter.hasNext())
    {
        System.out.println("Main Window ID : "+iter.next());
    }
    driver.findElement(By.id("lgnLogin_UserName")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("lgnLogin_UserName")).sendKeys(sh.getCell(0, 
    i).getContents());
    driver.findElement(By.id("lgnLogin_Password")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("lgnLogin_Password")).sendKeys(sh.getCell(1, 
  i).getContents());
    driver.findElement(By.id("lgnLogin_LoginButton")).click();
    Thread.sleep(5000L);

    windowids = driver.getWindowHandles();
    iter= windowids.iterator();
    String main_windowID=iter.next();
    String tabbed_windowID=iter.next();
    System.out.println("Main Window ID :" +main_windowID);
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    //switch over to pop-up window
    driver.switchTo().window(tabbed_windowID);

    System.out.println("Pop-up window Title : "+driver.getTitle());
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='BtnClose']")).click();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    driver.switchTo().window(main_windowID);
    msg= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@id='lgnLogin']/tbody/tr/td/table
  /tbody/tr[4]/td")).getText();
    System.out.println(msg);
    Thread.sleep(2000);

//  driver.get("https://www.700creditsolution.com");
//  Thread.sleep(2000);

    for (int j = 0; j < sh.getColumns(); j++) 
    {
        Label lab=new Label(j,i,sh.getCell(j, i).getContents());    
        ws.addCell(lab);
        Label result = new Label(2,i, msg);
        ws.addCell(result); 
        String c2String = sh.getCell(2, i).getContents().toString();
        if(c2String.equalsIgnoreCase(msg))
        {
            Label status=new Label(3,i,"Pass");
            ws.addCell(status);
        }
        else
        {
            Label status=new Label(3,i,"Fail");
            ws.addCell(status);
        }
    }
    }

    Label un=new Label(0,0,"User ID");
    Label pw=new Label(1,0,"Password");
    Label rs=new Label(2,0,"Results");
    Label st=new Label(3,0,"Status");
    ws.addCell(un);
    ws.addCell(pw);
    ws.addCell(rs);
    ws.addCell(st);
            wwb.write();
            wwb.close();

    driver.quit();

}   
}
```

Please help me on this issue ASAP. In my system I have windows7, IE9. My application best supports only in IE. Help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is the error when the script fails?

Comment: The Error get at this location. driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='BtnClose']")).click(); The error message displayed is "log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager). log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly. Main Window ID : ac70653a-8834-4843-bfde-16b229beed98 Main Window ID : 28deebd4-025e-4eaa-8c66-e59e24e39332 Main Window ID :ac70653a-8834-4843-bfde-16b229beed98 Pop-up window Title : Disable User Alert                                                        Disabled Due To InActivity

Comment: Main Window ID :8b92c617-8072-4b25-aa11-47fdc0b54477
Pop-up window Title : 700Dealers Inc.
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with xpath == //*[@id='BtnClose'] (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 280 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.21.0', revision: '16552', time: '2012-04-11 19:08:38'System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version:'6.1', java.version:'1.6.0_23'

Comment: Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:175)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:128)

Comment: at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:459)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:227)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:312)
 at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElement(By.java:344)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:219) at  Example.Script1.main(Script1.java:62)                               Please find the error message displayed in above 3 comments. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: is the issue still there?  since u hv already accepted the answer..

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Issue still exists.

Comment: U can probably put a breakpoint just after switching to the new window to figure out whether the btnclose does indeed appear on the screen

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have tried all the possible ways, but no success on this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a single exception you handled in your code.

Run the script, if it fails try to understand the exception, why exception is being generated and handle it properly, repeat this until you handle all the exceptions. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried by using Try & Catch method to handle the exception but, it is still giving error to me.       catch (NoSuchElementException e)
    {
     System.out.println("Element Error: " +e);
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
  catch (WebDriverException f)
  {
   System.out.println("WebDriver Error: " +f);
   f.printStackTrace();
  // f.toString();
  }
     catch (Throwable any)
     {
           System.out.println("Java ERROR: "+any);
           any.printStackTrace();
        }

Comment: Catching the exceptions is not enough. You've to properly handle them.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you please help me out how to handle the exception. As i am new to Java & Webdriver.

Comment: If an exception occurred, you've to find out why it has occurred and you've to write the code to avoid it occurring in the future. Thanks.